# select data from database using checkboxes in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, checkbox

I am working on customise report of a user.In this page I give a option of user check boxes for select data from database.Means user select the data which he wants to see from table.My table have many fields like name , block,contact..and so more. If users wants to see only uid and name only then he check the boxes of name and phone only.
my checkboxes are

```
       <form action="#" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="uid"><label>uid</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="name"><label>name</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="block"><label>block</label>....and so more
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and php code I am trying is

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $sql[] = "select ";

    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
        $sql[]=$selected.',';
    }  

    $sql[]= " from emitra_basic LIMIT 5";

    foreach ($sql as $user) {

        $ram="$user";
    }

    if ($result=mysqli_query($conn, $ram))
    { 
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        { 
            echo "id".$row['uid']."<br/>";
            echo "name".$row['name']."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

But No result.what should i try?

Comment: Could you put ur Create table query. How will we test if you wont put it?

Comment: Please re-format your code. It's unreadable.

Comment: Try to use ajax or javascript so anytime the user select/deselect a checkbox, the result will display automatically without refreshing the page or clicking a button.

Comment: @plum my table is working fine .i am getting report in another pages correctly.no issue with table

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$sql[] = "select ".implode(', ', $_POST['check_list'])." from emitra_basic LIMIT 5";
```

instead of

```
$sql[] = "select ";
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
$sql[]=$selected.',';}  
$sql[]= " from emitra_basic LIMIT 5";
```

to get something like:

```
select uid, name, block from emitra_basic LIMIT 5;
```

Otherwise there will be one `,` at the end of the last field:

```
select uid, name, block, from emitra_basic LIMIT 5; -- This is not working!
```

Comment: please more explain needed for output

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:- No big change in your coding

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$sql=array();

$sql[] = "select ";

$sql[]=join(",", $_POST['check_list']);

$sql[]= " from emitra_basic LIMIT 5";

//print_r($sql);

foreach ($sql as $user) {

    //echo $user."<br>";

    $ram.=$user;
}

//echo $ram; exit;

//select uid, from emitra_basic LIMIT 5

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn, $ram))
{ 
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    { 
        echo "id".$row['uid']."<br/>";
        echo "name".$row['name']."<br/>";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this in php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$sql1 = "select ";
$sql2 = "";
$checklist = $_POST['check_list'];
$count = count($checklist);
if($count!=1){
    $count = $count-1;
    for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 
        $sql2 = $sql2.$checklist[$i].",";
    }
    $sql2 = $sql2.$checklist[$count];
} else{
    $sql2 = $checklist[0];
}
$sql3= " from emitra_basic LIMIT 5";
$totalSql =  $sql1.$sql2.$sql3;

 if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$totalSql))
     { while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
     { echo "id".$row['uid']."<br/>";
echo "name".$row['name']."<br/>";}}
```

}

Comment: This code will also result in something like `select ,uid, name, block from ...` so that there is an syntax error because of the first `,`?

Comment: modified with my own logic